# Scrapy, crawling a dynamic page with multiple pages

Tags: python, scrapy

For an assignment I am trying to build a spider which is able to fetch data from the "www.kaercher.com" webshop. All the products in the webshop are being called by an AJAX call. In order to load in more products, a button named "show more products", has to be pressed. I managed to fetch the required data from the corresponding URL which is being called by the AJAX Call.

*However, for my assignment, I am suppose to fetch all (all products/pages) of a certain product. I've been digging around but I can't find a solution. I suppose I am suppose to do something with "isTruncated = true", true indicates that more products can be loaded, false means that there are no more products.* **(FIXED)**

*When I manage to fetch the data from all the pages, I need to find a way to fetch all the data from a list of products (create a .csv file with multiple kaercher products, each product has a unique ID which can be seen in the URL, in this case the ID 20035386 is for the high pressure washer).* **(FIXED)**

Links:
Webshop: https://www.kaercher.com/nl/webshop/hogedrukreinigers-resultaten.html

High pressure washer: https://www.kaercher.com/nl/webshop/hogedrukreinigers-resultaten.html

API Url (page1): https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL

**OLD CODE**

Spider file

```
import scrapy
from krc.items import KrcItem
import json

class KRCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "krc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["kaercher.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = KrcItem()
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for company in data.get('products', []):
            item["productid"] = company["id"]
            item["name"] = company["name"]
            item["description"] = company["description"]
            item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"]
            yield item
```

Items file

```
import scrapy


class KrcItem(scrapy.Item):
    productid=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**NEW CODE**

**EDIT: 15/08/2019**

Thanks to @gangabass I managed to fetch data from all of the product pages. I also manages to fetch the data from different products which are listed in a keyword.csv file. This enables me to fetch data from a list of products. See below for the new code:

Spider file (.py)

```
import scrapy
from krc.items import KrcItem
import json
import os
import csv

class KRCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "krc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["kaercher.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL']

    def start_requests(self):
        """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                search_text=keyword["keyword"]
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(
                    search_text)
                # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text}) 

    def parse(self, response):
        current_page = response.meta.get("page", 1)
        next_page = current_page + 1

        item = KrcItem()
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for company in data.get('products', []):
            item["productid"] = company["id"]
            item["name"] = company["name"]
            item["description"] = company["description"]
            item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"].replace("\u20ac","").strip()
            yield item

        if data["isTruncated"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'page': next_page},
            )
```

Items file (.py)

```
import scrapy


class KrcItem(scrapy.Item):
    productid=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    producttype=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

keywords file (.csv)

```
keyword,keywordtype
20035386,Hogedrukreiniger
20072956,Floor Cleaner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `response.meta` to send current page number between requests:

```
def parse(self, response):
    current_page = response.meta.get("page", 1)
    next_page = current_page + 1

    item = KrcItem()
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    for company in data.get('products', []):
        item["productid"] = company["id"]
        item["name"] = company["name"]
        item["description"] = company["description"]
        item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"]
        yield item

    if data["isTruncated"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={'page': next_page},
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! I edited my Question and posted my full code in case somebody stumbles upon the same issue.